# Fire agenda groups separately in drools

Tags: java, drools, preload, rule

We are using Drools 6.

All my rules are divided into two category, prefetch rules and main rules.

I want to somehow fire all rules defined with agenda-group 'prefetch' first and then once it is finished, then fire agenda-group 'mainRules'.

Wondering, is that possible to do this and fire agenda groups separately from outside where we fire all the rules and still share the context between the two?

I've seen somewhere a method 'setAgendaFilter' but I can't find that in stateless session, not sure if it's been removed in Drools 6.

Can anyone help me on this?

PS.: Inside rules in group 'prefetch' we have 'insert' so that it causes the rules to be fired again, I don't want this causes to fire rules in group 'mainRules'

Answer (score 3):

With a StatefulKnowledgeSession (5.x) or a KieSession (6.x) kSession or you can

```
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup( "prefetch" ).setFocus();
kSession.fireAllRules();
kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup( "mainRules" ).setFocus();
kSession.fireAllRules();
```

Relax, and watching them blinkenlights.

Comment: kSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup( "prefetch" ).setFocus() throws UnsupportedOperationException... it's not implemented... not sure if this is because we are using old api or something else: StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();<br/> I tried ksession.getAgenda().setFocus("prefetch") this ignores the focus! Thanks anyway, I can't spend more time on this as I have other tasks to work on.

Comment: Tested with 6.0.0 and works without a hitch. - What't the point in posting if you aren't interested in solving the problem?

Comment: This isn't quite answering the question - it doesn't work with stateless sessions.

Comment: @Damnum "Stateless" is just a simplifying wrapper for "stateful"; in the scenarion required here, "stateful" is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at `ruleflow-group` in [drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e5177).

> Ruleflow is a Drools feature that lets you exercise control over the firing of rules. Rules that are assembled by the same ruleflow-group identifier fire only when their group is active.